# Site link crawler/checker as part of build process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, msbuild, automated-tests, integration-testing

When we build our MVC app, we have a build process that pushes the site on to our UAT box.

Once published, We would like to run an automated tool that crawls all the links in the app and checks for broken links and any other issues (such as usability/accessibility, etc.)

What tool(s) exists that will crawl a site and generate a report a report on broken links, etc.?

Can it be integrated in to our CI (TFS) Build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any alternative advice, we went with this solution:

http://wummel.github.com/linkchecker/

It's working well for us. One of the key advantages of this system is that it has a command-line mode with lots of options AND it can produce multiple format reports (HTML, Sitemap, CSV, XML) in a single crawl. Other tools I've used in the past had to run multiple times, consuming more bandwidth and time.

The beauty of this is that we can add it to our build process and then automate the output. When the build is pushed to UAT, LinkChecker runs. When it has finished, the HTML output is emailed to us and the XML output is parsed. All 404 errors are raised as bugs in TFS.

Quite a nice solution.